Хочу чтобы после срабатывания callback.data == 'urls' , бот снова присылал прошлое сообщение сообщение callback.data == 'helper'
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot=telebot.TeleBot("my_tocken")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сайт на Django',callback_data='django'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Выберите что вам нужно', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):

    if callback.data == 'helper':
        helps = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        helps.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Как отслеживать url адреса?', callback_data='urls'))
        helps.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Как выводить текст на сайт?', callback_data='texts'))
        helps.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Как работать с HTML шаблоном?', callback_data='htmls'))
        helps.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Вернуться назад', callback_data='django'))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите что вам напомнить?', reply_markup=helps)



    if callback.data == 'urls':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В папке main создать папку urls.py")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "В taskmanager/urls.py введи path(‘ что отслеживаешь ‘)")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Убери то что над прошлым сообщением ")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Вместо from admin… напиши from . import что отслеживаешь")

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


В Telebot не очень много возможностей, тем более он уже устарел лучше использовать AIOGRAM

Да, но хочется знать как работать и там и там

А в чем проблема, почему просто не добавьте его в условие?)
